# Change zoom factor in Bing Maps WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-maps

When you use the wheel of the mouse on the map, it's to zoom more or less like we see on Bing Maps or Google Maps. I saw that the factor of zooming is 1.2 everytime you scroll. I've been asked to change it because it was zooming too far or too close. So is it even possible?

I tried by using the MouseWheel event and manage the zoom myself by disabling it with "e.Handled = true;". It worked in a way, but I lose the animation that comes with it and also the zoom is pointing the current center of the map instead of the the cursor of the mouse.

Any help would be appreciated even if it's to say that it's not possible.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check if the [SetView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh709343.aspx) method is animating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the current implementation is doing:

In `OnMouseWheel` it calls the following method:

```
this.ZoomAboutViewportPoint(((double) e.Delta) / 100.0, e.GetPosition(this));
```

It's implementation is:

```
private void ZoomAboutViewportPoint(double zoomLevelIncrement, Point zoomTargetInViewport)
{
    base.ZoomAndRotateOrigin = new Point?(zoomTargetInViewport);
    base.ViewBeingSetByUserInput = true;
    base.SetView((double) (base.TargetZoomLevel + zoomLevelIncrement), base.TargetHeading);
    base.ViewBeingSetByUserInput = false;
}
```

Obviously you cant set `base.ViewBeingSetByUserInput` and `base.ZoomAndRotateOrigin` directly as they are internal.

You can however just use `SetView` accordingly with the viewport coordinates, but will still loose the nice animation part.

Alternatively you can set the aforementioned values via reflection, but that is a brittle hack and prone to break if the control changes.

**--- UPDATE**

As described above: If you hook up to the `MouseWheel` Event here is the code to make it work via the reflection call of the private method:

```
void BingMap_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
  {
     e.Handled = true;

     System.Reflection.MethodInfo dynMethod = this.BingMap.GetType().GetMethod("ZoomAboutViewportPoint", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
     dynMethod.Invoke(this.BingMap, new object[] { (((double)e.Delta) / 400d), e.GetPosition(this.BingMap) });


  }
```

This brings it down to a quarter of the speed and makes it usable with the least amount of code. But again this is a hack!

Comment: Knowing what the implementation of the mouse is really helps. If I put the AnimationLevel to "Full", I can still have the animation part when using SetView, so that's great. Now, I just need to figure out the pattern with the ZoomAndRotateOrigin to center the map according to the cursor actual position.

Comment: Isn't there a `SetView` where you describe the center like `MapCore.SetView (Location, Double)`. That should do the trick.

Comment: Usually when you are scrolling, the center moves according to the position of the cursor of the mouse. It doesn't stay at the same center location when zooming. That's what I'm trying to accomplish now, because yes we can set the center with SetView.

Comment: AFTER UPDATE : This just solved my problem, it's a hack but it works great now! Thanks!